# Move to a view in storyboard via Database Update

Tags: objective-c

My method of storing data is located in AppDelegate.  Whenever the data has been saved into database, I want to check if SecondView isVisible.
If it is, then reload the value on the screen from database.
If not, I'll display the view with the latest value on the screen.

I'm trying something like this:

delegate.m

```
    //  I want to update view
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
  SecondViewController *SecondVC = (SecondViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SecondVC"];
  if (SecondVC.isVisible)
  {
    NSLog(@"SecondVC is visible");
    [SecondVC updateDisplayValue];

  }
  else
  {
    self.window.rootViewController = SecondVC;
    NSLog(@"SecondVC not visible");
  }
```

SecondViewController.m

```
  - (BOOL)isVisible {
    return [self isViewLoaded] && self.view.window;
  }

- (void)updateDisplayValue
{
  [self LatestMeasurementFromSQLite];
  [self.date setText:self.measurementTime];
}
```

It's not working as it should, the isVisible never return is visible, and updateDisplayValue does not update the already displayed view.

I believe the problem is that I've reinitiated a new view called SecondVC, which is not the one displayed on the screen.  But how can AppDelegate get a hold of the current display view?

Please help!  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

At the time you check SecondVC.isVisible, it won't be visible because you just created it, and its view hasn't been loaded yet. I'm not sure how to correct it -- it depends on your controller structure. Is that first bit of code in the app delegate?